# Specifying number of decimal places in tbl_survfit from gtsummary

Tags: r, gtsummary

I'm using `tbl_survfit` from `gtsummary` to make a table of survival probabilities with 95% confidence interval at certain time points. I would like to specify the number of decimal places.

I understand there is an argument `estimate_fun` that seems involved in this and I tried to pass style_percent(digits = 3). I got an error because it requires a numeric vector of percentages as an argument and I haven't been able to find what numeric vector to pass.

Comment: The `estimate_fun=` argument expects a proper function, something like this: `estimate_fun = function(x) style_number(x, digits = 3, scale = 100)`.

Comment: I can't recall whether you need the scale argument here to scale the probabilities on the 0 to 1 scale to the 0 to 100 scale. But you'll see if it's needed immediately after creating the table.

Comment: @DanielD.Sjoberg Thank you for your reply. I got it to work by passing `estimate_fun = ~gtsummary::style_sigfig(.x, digits = 1, scale = 100)`. What should be passed for the x in your example `style_number(x, digits = 3, scale = 100)`, when using `tbl_survfit`?